# Работа str_replace с кириллицей, utf-8

Tags: php, строки, utf-8, кириллица

Подскажите, как вы выходите из положения когда нужно вырезать какое-то кириллическое слово, букву из текста. (`str_replace` не работает) 
Пробовал самописные функции по типу `mb_str_replace` - ни одна не дала должного результата.

**Пример:** 
Допустим у нас есть строка: `$calc = "1ч20мин+1ч50мин";` 
И из нее нужно убрать "мин".

Или же более сложные случаи, где много спарсенного текста (начальная кодировка заранее неизвестна) и в нем нужно что-то изменить.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что str_replace не работает? Покажите, пожалуйста, пример

Comment: Все прекрасно работает - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18bba68d3bdfc42d5d3f04c0597cf460215fa709

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если исходная кодировка заранее неизвестна и например нужно привести текст к общей кодировке utf-8.

```
<?php
$str = "1ч20мин+1ч50мин";

$charset = mb_detect_encoding($str);

$str = iconv($charset, "UTF-8", $str);

$str = str_replace("мин", "", $str);

echo $str;

//1ч20+1ч50
?>
```

tets online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a1a8ab1688b23cfbe03aa40c7d722600b57789b

Comment: Да, нашел ошибку в разности кодировок, из-за этого и возникала проблема.

Answer (score 3):

Вы делаете что-то неправильно, функция str_replace успешно работает на данном кейсе.

```
$t = str_replace("мин", "", "1час5мин");
echo $t; //1час5
```

[Документация PHP по str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [,
>   int &$count ] )

Если Вы хотите перевести строку в другую кодировку, воспользуйтесь функцией [iconv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "hello");
```