# Вставка символов юникода в строку

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Сайт работает в кодировке Windows-1251, в том числе и соединение с базой MySQL. Все файлы сохранены в Windows-1251.

Появилась необходимость сделать замену слов в строке, с помощью `str_replace`.

Замена обычных символов, типа

```
str_replace("Слово", "Замена", $str);
```

работает хорошо.

Но возникла проблема при замене слова на слово с символами юникода.

Как только я прописал

```
str_replace("Слово", "кοᴛοᴘыᴇ", $str);
```

редактор кода выдал сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сохранил файл в UTF-8, но замена слова не произошла в строке, осталось прежнее слово `Слово` .

Что можно сделать?

Comment: Код php файла сохраняйте в кодировке win-1251.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563965/19815

Comment: @Visman но редактор не дает этого сделать если вставить символы юникода. выдает сообщение (скрин в вопросе)

Comment: @n.osennij там был уже. не помогло

Comment: Берите тот редактор который может сохранять файлы в однобайтовых кодировках. В строке `str_replace("Слово", "кοᴛοᴘыᴇ", $str);` нет ни одного символа, которого бы не было в win-1251.

Comment: @Visman удалось сохранить в win-1251 с помощью Notepad++ . но теперь слово кοᴛοᴘыᴇ на сайте отображает так `к????ы?`

Comment: Вы в сохраненный файл-то посмотрите, что там за слово получилось :)

Comment: @Visman в Notepad++ я вижу `кοᴛοᴘыᴇ` а в Sublime Text 2 - `к????ы?`

Comment: Посмотрите на это слово в шестнадцатеричном формате просмотра файлов, чтобы коды символов были видны. В тотал командере такой режим просмотра файлов был. Вот таблица символов https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251 для сверки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я протестировал этот код у себя и это у меня сработало:

```
$str = "Слово";
echo "<p>$str</p>"; // Слово

$str =  str_replace("Слово", "кοᴛοᴘыᴇ", $str);
echo "<p>$str</p>"; // Результат: которые
```

Но у меня есть и другой функция для вас чтобы заменить ключ в значение в ассоциативном массиве. Вот пример функции и использование:

#### Сама функция:

```
function replaceKeyToValue($request, $dict){
    $response = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($dict) {
        $word = mb_strtolower($m[0]);
        if (isset($dict[$word])) {
            $repl = $dict[$word];
            if ($word === $m[0]) return $repl;
            if (mb_strtoupper($word) === $m[0]) return mb_strtoupper($repl);
            if (mb_convert_case($word,  MB_CASE_TITLE) === $m[0]) return mb_convert_case($repl,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
            for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($word); $i < $len; ++$i) {
                $mixed[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1) === mb_substr($m[0], $i, 1) 
                    ? mb_substr($repl, $i, 1)
                    : mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($repl, $i, 1));
            }
            return implode("", $mixed);
        }
        return $m[0];
    }, $request);
    return $response;
}
```

#### Пример массива:

```
$array = array
(
  'слово' => 'которые'
);
```

#### Пример использование:

```
$str = "слово Слово СЛОВО";

echo replaceKeyToValue($str, $array);
```

#### Результат:

```
которые Которые КОТОРЫЕ
```

То есть функция выводит ответ в том регистре в каком он и написано в входном тексте. Но не работает если вы например будете использовать разные регистры: `"СлОвО слОВО СлоВо"`
Поэтому рекомендуется использовать или нижний или верхний или начало с верхним а далее с нижним регистром `"слово СЛОВО Слово"`

Comment: Это вообще что такое было? Автору вопроса всего лишь нужно файл в кодировке win-1251 сохранить. Тем более ваша функция не сможет заменить подстроки в строке, если они в разных кодировках!