# Функция str_replace работая с переменной а не со строкой не срабатывает

Tags: php, str-replace

Код php, для примера использую строку и переменную

```
 $active_series_done=''.$elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE'].'';
            $active_series_done1='"';
            $active_series_done2='';
            $active_series_done3='ЭМАЛЬ  "ПТИЧИЙ ДВОРИК';
            $active_series_done4='"';
            $active_series_done5='';
            echo '<pre>';
            echo $active_series_done.'<br>';
            echo $active_series_done3 ;
            echo '</pre>'; 
            $active_series_done3=str_replace($active_series_done4, $active_series_done5, $active_series_done3);
            $active_series_done=str_replace($active_series_done1, $active_series_done2, $active_series_done);
             echo '<pre>';
            echo $active_series_done.'<br>';
            echo $active_series_done3;
            echo '</pre>';
```

результат :[image: результат работы кода выше]

Код без одинарных кавычек:

```
$active_series_done=$elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE'];
            $active_series_done1='"';
            $active_series_done2='';
            $active_series_done3='ЭМАЛЬ  "ПТИЧИЙ ДВОРИК';
            $active_series_done4='"';
            $active_series_done5='';
            echo '<pre>';
            echo $active_series_done.'<br>';
            echo $active_series_done3 ;
            echo '</pre>'; 
            $active_series_done3=str_replace($active_series_done4, $active_series_done5, $active_series_done3);
            $active_series_done=str_replace($active_series_done1, $active_series_done2, $active_series_done);
             echo '<pre>';
            echo $active_series_done.'<br>';
            echo $active_series_done3;
            echo '</pre>';
```

[image: Результат без одинарных кавычек]

Почему str_replace не срабатывает?

сравнил переменную, с результатом после str_replace:

```
$active_series_done3=str_replace($active_series_done4, $active_series_done5, $active_series_done3);
            $active_series_done=$elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE'];
            $active_series_done1='"';
            $active_series_done2='';
            $active_series_done10=str_replace($active_series_done1, $active_series_done2, $active_series_done);

            if($active_series_done===$active_series_done10){
                echo 'равны';
            }
```

Результат они равны:[image: смотреть]

применил к переменной функцию htmlspecialchars() :

```
$active_series_done=htmlspecialchars($elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE']);
```

Результат [image: htmlspecialchars]

Comment: значит, там другие кавычки. приведите в вопросе результат `var_export($active_series_done);`

Comment: 'ЭМАЛЬ "ПТИЧИЙ ДВОРИК'

Comment: если меняю вместо кавычек букву "П" все нормально

Comment: не знаю, кавычка вроде как кавычка. Но чудес не бывает

Comment: Мб он видит как символ html, а я удаляю просто символ

Comment: var_export дает воспроизводимый результат. если взять приведенный вами вывод и подставить в переменную, все работает

Comment: посмотрите код страницы, какие проблемы

Comment: В php если бы проблемы были то ошибку на странице выдавало, о каких проблемах вы говорите? я перевел htmlspecialchars и хочу удалить "&quot;" он не срабатывает, хотя "quot" удаляет и  знак ";"

Comment: Мне приходится проводить такие операции чтобы привести к нужному виду: $active_series_done=str_replace('quot','', $active_series_done);
   $active_series_done=str_replace('&','', $active_series_done);
   $active_series_done=str_replace(';','', $active_series_done);
   $active_series_done=str_replace('amp','', $active_series_done);

Comment: А что выдаст `echo mb_detect_encoding($elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE']);` ?

Comment: в строке есть ASCII и е сть UTF-8

Comment: http://prntscr.com/sl5qyf

Comment: а вардампом php эту строку за что считает? 
$elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE']

Comment: Попробуйте с приведением кодировки пошаманить как здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563874/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-str-replace-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9-utf-8

Comment: если я заливаю в файл file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ratio.txt', date("d.m.Y H:i:s -- ") . 'переменная ' . var_export($elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE'], true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    то выдает 'ЭМАЛЬ  &quot;ПТИЧИЙ ДВОРИК'

Comment: значит я у этой переменной убираю  &quot; и все работает $active_series_done10=$elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE'];
   $active_series_done10=str_replace('&quot;','', $active_series_done10);
   echo $active_series_done10;

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что в переменной знак " это был знак " когда я писал 
$active_series_done=str_replace('"', '',$elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE'] ); он просто не видел символ ", поэтому я написал так: $active_series_done=str_replace('"', '',$elcat['PROPERTY_SERIYA_VALUE'] ); и код заработал